# Select list array - prepopulate the choice to the top of the array

Tags: php

I am printing a simple select list out by looping through an associative array which is populated elsewhere.

```
<select id="choice" name="choice">
    <?php 
    foreach ($this->choice as $key => $value) { 
    echo "<option name=".$value." value=".$key.">" .$value. "</option>" ; 
    } 
    ?>
</select>
```

This select list gives the options available from the array.  However, I am trying to pre-populate the list with the selected value, for example if a user is updating their user information, then I would like to set that choice at the top of the list (ideally without the choice appearing further down the list).

I have access to this data in a variable which I have queried:

```
$this->selected_choice //value
$this->selected_id //key
```

Now I have been testing some solutions

```
<select id="choice" name="choice">
    <option name="<?php echo $this->selected_choice; ?>" value="<?php echo $this->selected_id;?>">"<?php echo $this->selected_choice; ?></option>
    <?php 
    foreach ($this->choice as $key => $value) { 
    echo "<option name=".$value." value=".$key.">" .$value. "</option>" ; 
    } 
    ?>
</select>
```

This solution does display the users choice on top of the list, but the foreach loop will also display this option as there is no indication that it shouldn't.

This is my question to you guys, how can I do this so the the selected_choice appears at the top of the list, but will then not appear in the foreach array.

I am hoping there is some simple solution to this problem, as it is not so important, but something I come across quite a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option have no "**name**". Name is attribute **for SELECT** tag. 
If option is selected, you need to pass "**selected**" attribute in body of option
Ex: `<option value="1" selected>Tramtada</option>`

Do it this way:

```
  <select id="choice" name="choice">
    <?php 
      foreach ($this->choice as $key => $value) { 
        echo "<option <?php if($key == $this->selected_id) {?> selected <?php } ?> value=".$key.">" .$value. "</option>" ; 
      } 
    ?>
  </select>
```

Comment: That's fair enough, I wrote it from my head so that is a little mistake, but i am not sure passing a selected attribute will remove the choice printed below from the foreach array?  I am trying to avoid any duplicates, 1 being the users predefined choice, and the other being an legitimate choice from the array which will be displayed directly below.

Comment: Try second version, u will get selected attribute on the top.

Comment: Great, this works, I had to make a little adjustment to the syntax but this is what I was looking for!